# Fill pandas dataframe record with empty field, with data from another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AREA': ['P1', 'P1'],
    'GROUP': ['GROUP1', None],
    'VALUE': [0, 2]
})
```

And

```
df_groups = pd.DataFrame({
    'GROUP': ['GROUP1', 'GROUP2', 'GROUP3']
})
```

Where record is None, then I must fill with all existing groups in dataframe df_groups

The expected result

```
  AREA   GROUP  VALUE
0   P1  GROUP1      0
1   P1  GROUP1      2
1   P1  GROUP2      2
1   P1  GROUP3      2
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
(df.assign(GROUP=df['GROUP'].map({None: df_groups['GROUP'].tolist()})
                            .fillna(df['GROUP']))
   .explode('GROUP')
)
```

Output:

```
  AREA   GROUP  VALUE
0   P1  GROUP1      0
1   P1  GROUP1      2
1   P1  GROUP2      2
1   P1  GROUP3      2
```

Or with a custom [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
(df.merge(df_groups.assign(key=None), left_on='GROUP', right_on='key',
          how='left', suffixes=(None, '_'))
   .assign(GROUP=lambda d: d['GROUP'].fillna(d.pop('GROUP_')))
   .drop(columns='key')
)
```

Output:

```
  AREA   GROUP  VALUE
0   P1  GROUP1      0
1   P1  GROUP1      2
2   P1  GROUP2      2
3   P1  GROUP3      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AREA': ['P1', 'P1'],
    'GROUP': ['GROUP1', None],
    'VALUE': [0, 2]
})

df_groups = pd.DataFrame({
    'GROUP': ['GROUP1', 'GROUP2', 'GROUP3']
})

# replace None in 'GROUP' column with list of groups from df_groups
df['GROUP'] = df['GROUP'].apply(lambda x: df_groups['GROUP'].tolist() if pd.isnull(x) else [x])

# explode the 'GROUP' column
df = df.explode('GROUP')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options

Since `df.fillna()` cannot accept lists one option is to combine the items in df_groups and use `str.split`:

```
df.fillna({'GROUP':','.join(df_groups['GROUP'])}).assign(GROUP = lambda x: x['GROUP'].str.split(',')).explode('GROUP')
```

or create a series of lists:

```
df.fillna({'GROUP':pd.Series([list(df_groups['GROUP'])]*len(df))}).explode('GROUP')
```

or use a cross join in `pd.merge`

```
m = df['GROUP'].isna()
df2 = pd.merge(df.loc[m],df_groups,how = 'cross',suffixes=('','_'))

pd.concat([df.loc[~m],df2.fillna({'GROUP':df2.pop('GROUP_')})])
```

Output:

```
  AREA   GROUP  VALUE
0   P1  GROUP1      0
1   P1  GROUP1      2
1   P1  GROUP2      2
1   P1  GROUP3      2
```